# How to downgrade Win 10 to Win 8.1 - Need to remove 'new accounts' like NT SERVICE\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS and IIS AppPool\

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have a PC with Windows 8.1 (not pro) that was upgraded to Win 10. We've since realised the PC wasn't 'Pro' so need to upgrade to Win 10 pro. I was advised that a Win 10 Pro Pack isn't available yet so the only way is to downgrade to 8.1, then apply a Pro Pack, then upgrade again to Win 10 Pro. 
Upon trying to downgrade I've received a message saying

> Remove new accounts
>
> Before you can go back to a previous version of Windows, you'll need
>   to remove any user accounts you added after your most recent upgrade.
>   The accounts need to be completely removed, including their profiles.
>
> You created 6 accounts (IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool, NT
>   SERVICE\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS, IIS APPPOOL.NET v2.0 Classic, ...)
>
> Go to Settings > Accounts > Other users to remove these accounts, and
>   then try again.

Of course these virtual accounts aren't listed in the settings page or in Computer Management > Local Users and Groups and [cannot be deleted](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548356%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). How do I remove these so I can downgrade, or make the downgrade process ignore them?

Someone else has posted a similar problem [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3i03xh/unable_to_downgrade_because_of_iisapppoolnet/) and I've posted it on the [MS forums here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/cant-downgrade-win10-to-81-need-to-remove-new/feb43777-6054-42cb-a588-9d10da168006?tm=1440430734103&auth=1).

Answer (score 3):

#### New accounts prevents Windows 10 rollback

Use **one** of the solutions below and then try again to rollback.

---

#### Solution 1

> 1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `sysdm.cpl` andpress <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 2. Click on "Advanced" tab.
> 3. Click on "Settings"  under the "User Profiles" section.
> 4. On the "User Profiles" dialog select the `<COMPUTER NAME>\<Account Name>` and click  on "Delete".
> 5. Confirm the delete.
> 6. Repeat steps 4 and 5 for each account to be deleted.
>
> Warning:
>
> The above steps will also delete all data associated with the accounts – > please ensure data associated with the
>   account is backed up if necessary prior to performing the steps.

Source [Roll Back of Windows 10](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/roll-back-of-windows-10/2a669c0f-4dfb-4ef6-8118-f0faba6e298e)

---

#### Solution 2

> Please go to the registry editor and do the following steps:
>
> 1. Click <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, to open run command. Type "regedit" and click enter.
> 2. Create a back of the registry. Click on Hkey and go to the File Tab, press Export and save it to your desired your location.
> 3. Go to the provided path `HKey_LocalMachine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>      NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`.
> 4. In the profile list you will find a few SID's please find the ones related to the accounts to be deleted and delete them.
>
> To know which SID is related to the Account you wish to delete
>   look at each SID series and on the right side look for
>   ProfileImagePath, you will notice `c:/users/<Account Name>`.

Source [Go back to Windows 7 with User account issue](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/go-back-to-windows-7-with-user-account-issue/63e30e33-0664-4810-8c73-5cc0c38225e4?auth=1)

Comment: Many thanks. Unfortunately my colleague gave up and reimaged back to 8.1 ... but I'm sure this will be helpful to others.